# how to reopen a PR in github after a force push

Tags: github

In my PR, there were three commits. I accidently deleted those three commits. Because of that, my PR has been closed.

Now I need to reopen the same PR with new commits?

I tried few solutions available, but I didn't understand the process. I appreciate if anyone explain this.

Comment: Delete the branch in GIT UI, and re push the branch again with all changes

Comment: This doesn't make the closed PR..open right?

Comment: open the closed PR commit and you change from closed to open

Comment: I couldn't able to do open it in my github.

Comment: There will be a commit ID near closed tag, just click on that

Comment: might help (I've not tried) - https://gist.github.com/robertpainsi/2c42c15f1ce6dab03a0675348edd4e2c